# Select query working abnormally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am confused by the nature of logical operators upon datetime data in sql.

In my database's table RecordDateTime is saved like:

```
2014-04-09 15:28:32.000
```

I am retrieving on basis of this query:

```
select 
    * 
from [GPSDB].[dbo].[Coordinates] 
where IMEI= '354400055967495' 
    and RecordedDateTime >= '2014-04-09 15:28:32.000' 
    and RecordedDateTime <= '2014-04-09 15:39:20.000'
```

Now it returns 4 rows which falls between these both dates range or equal as expected but confusion starts from here when i remove Seconds part from first date then still it works and returns same result set i.e.

```
select 
    * 
from [GPSDB].[dbo].[Coordinates] 
where IMEI = '354400055967495'
    and RecordedDateTime >= '2014-04-09 15:28' 
    and RecordedDateTime <= '2014-04-09 15:39:20.000'
```

but if i remove seconds part from 2nd date then it returns only one row with matching time of first date being provided. Weird ? :/

Help Please.

Comment: Hard to say without you showing us some data. I suspect that three of the four entries have a timestamp between 15:39:00 and 15:39:20. That's all. If course, they are not returned if you remove the seconds from the second timestamp.

Comment: Can you provide your resultset or the dates part of it.

Answer (score 0):

the datetime data `2014-04-09 15:28:32.000` have two part date part `2014-04-09` and time part `15:28:32.000`.

So when you say

`RecordedDateTime >= '2014-04-09 15:28:32.000' and RecordedDateTime <= '2014-04-09 15:39:20.000'`

It will consider the time part as well and since there is 11 minutes gap between; it will fetch you all those record which falls in that range.

But when you say below, it will consider only the date part for comparison and there is only 1 day and hence it will fetch the first record of that date `2014-04-09`

```
RecordedDateTime >= '2014-04-09' 
and RecordedDateTime <= '2014-04-09'
```